# Chrome Bug: Unsafe Javascript attempt

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, dns, xss

I have an iframe on my page. The page housed within the iframe is of the same domain. I am experiencing an error with the page in the iframe when attempting to open a pop-up window in the iframe.

Below is a snapshot of the error message i receive from the chrome console.

[image: Chrome bug]
<sub>(source: [farfromthere.org](http://farfromthere.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Chrome-iframe-bug.png))</sub>

The functionality of the pop-up in the iframe works great when using firefox. So this appears to only be a chrome issue. As you can see the main page and the iframe are both on the same domain and are both HTTPS protocol.

I don't know if this is a bug, or if i'm doing something wrong.

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318788/unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-with-url)